# Front-End Upload media with category

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, front-end

Hello i have a page with a little uploader to upload media in the library, here is my code :

```
            <?php 
                $post_id = $post->ID;
                if ( isset( $_POST['html-upload'] ) && !empty( $_FILES ) ) {
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
                    $id = media_handle_upload('async-upload', $post_id); //post id of Client Files page
                    unset($_FILES);
                    if ( is_wp_error($id) ) {
                        $errors['upload_error'] = $id;
                        $id = false;
                    }

                    if ($errors) {
                        echo "<p>There was an error uploading your file.</p>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<p>Your file has been uploaded.</p>";
                    }
                }

            ?>
```

With my form :

```
<form id="file-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="POST">

<p id="async-upload-wrap"><label for="async-upload">upload</label>
<input type="file" id="async-upload" name="async-upload"> <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="html-upload"></p>

<p><input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>" />
<?php wp_nonce_field('client-file-upload'); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save all changes" name="save" style="display: none;"></p>
<form>
```

And my snippet to enable category and tag to media :

```
// add categories for attachments
function add_categories_for_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_categories_for_attachments' );

// add tags for attachments
function add_tags_for_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_tags_for_attachments' );
```

Everything work great. I can upload, it's working. I can select category in media library on back.
Now i just want a checkbox or list to select existant category to attach them to the uploaded media before uploading.

I don't now if i'm clear but i'm not native english. :)

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can assign attachment to those categories after upload? Check this example.

```
function add_category_automatically($post_ID) {
    $attach = get_post($post_ID);
    if ($attach->post_parent) {
        $cats = get_the_category()($attach->post_parent);
        foreach ($cats as $cat) {
            wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $cat->slug, 'category', true);
        }
    }
}
add_action('add_attachment', 'add_category_automatically');
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751478/automatic-category-assignment-upon-attachment-upload)